# Rails 3 - more cycle helpers in one main loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, cycle, helper

Good morning guys,

I have one big loop, in that are 3 others. The main loop uses `cycle` for set background color of every row. In one of 3 loops is `cycle` helper used too -- and I got "error", because is conflict among these two `cycle`s. I solved this situation with `each_with_index`, but - is possible use in this situation `cycle` helper? Is possible the second `cycle` separate something?

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple cycles in one loop by naming them:

```
<%= cycle("even", "odd", :name => "first_cycler" %>
```